# How to add printf to successful query return in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have this code:

```
$query = mysql_query("CALL dodaj_osobe ('$pesel','$imie','$nazwisko','$telefon','$adres','$nr_konta','$zarobek')"); 
print "DONE";
```

But it works when the query isn't successful as well.

How can I change this to "if this query is done successfully then `printf` this text, in other way `printf` nothing"?

Comment: I think this is a good opportunity to try something out: Go to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) and find out what the `mysql_query` function returns. Also, you'll note, that mysql_* is being deprecated - you should switch to mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: @Nicarus - perhaps that person needs to learn programming. I know that is a silly thought, but I am a heritic.

Comment: What happens when the stored procedure fails? Does it for example just return empty data set? Basically, does the query actually fail, or does it return data you can recognise as an error (which is an error to you, but a successfully run query to MySQL).

Comment: @EdHeal - I think your comment is the less 'PC' version of what I was trying to say, but agreed. :-)

Comment: Call a spade a spade - @Nicarus

Comment: @EdHeal - Maybe I am naive. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query('your SQL query');
if (!$result) {
    print('error: ' . mysql_error()); // an error occured
}
else
{
    print('Done');
}
```

try to use mysqli, because mysql_query is deprecated:
[mysqli manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

a simple mysqli exmaple:

```
<?php
// New Connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');
$result = $db->query("your SQL query");
if($result)
{
     // Cycle through results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $group_arr[] = $row;
    }
     // Free result set
     $result->close();
     $db->next_result();
}
else 
{
    echo($db->error); // an error occured, print the error
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, stop using the old deprecated `mysql_*`.

I'm not going to show you how to do what you want with `mysql_*` because I don't want to. In PDO, you would do:

```
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=dbHost;dbName=yourDBName;' , 'user' , 'pass' );

try
{
   $st = $db->prepare("CALL dodaj_osobe (pesel:,imie:,nazwisko:,telefon:,adres:,nr_konta:,zarobek:)");
   $st->bindValue( 'pesel:' , $pesel , PDO::PARAM_dataType );
   $st->bindValue( 'imie:' , $imie , PDO::PARAM_dataType );
   $st->bindValue( 'nazwisko:' , $nazwisko , PDO::PARAM_dataType );
   $st->bindValue( 'telefon:' , $telefon , PDO::PARAM_dataType );
   $st->bindValue( 'adres:' , $adres , PDO::PARAM_dataType );
   $st->bindValue( 'nr_konta:' , $nr_konta , PDO::PARAM_dataType );
   $st->bindValue( 'zarobek:' , $zarobek , PDO::PARAM_dataType );
   $st->execute();
}
catch( PDOException $qEx )
{
   //the query wasn't successful..
   //deal with it
}
```

Replace all `PDO::PARAM_dataType` with whatever data type the var for the named place holder is. So for example, if `$pesel` is a string, replace `$st->bindValue( 'pesel:' , $pesel , PDO::PARAM_dataType );` with `$st->bindValue( 'pesel:' , $pesel , PDO::PARAM_STR );`. Notice the PARAM_STR?..

If the OOP approach confuses you, use MySQLi as it supports the procedural approach.

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP maual: `mysql_query() returns a resource on success`, or `FALSE` on error.

So, if you want the exact result of this function, can write like this;

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
if (false !== $result) {
    // it's ok!
} else {
    // error!
}
```

In addition, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. See more details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php